# Android Fix Floating Numeric Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I initially started making an application on a Samsung Tab 3, and recently changed to a Samsung Active tablet. Since making the change, I noticed that the numeric keyboard is detached from the bottom of the screen, and is movable. I really want the numeric keyboard to be locked to the bottom of the screen, just like the regular keyboard.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Note: I'm running version 4.4.4

Comment: I think what you are seeing is a floating keyboard which can be again reset to its default just by tapping and holding the keyboard icon and choosing the option from the pop up that is displayed. More details in the following link: http://galaxys5guide.com/samsung-galaxy-s5-how-to-guides/how-to-use-galaxy-s5-samsung-keyboard/

Comment: You're right! It is a floating keyboard.But I can't find a way to change it on the numeric keyboard. Any ideas?

Comment: I am guessing, this floating behavior is not limited to your application. So maybe, you could try going to some another application, maybe messaging can try to invoke the keyboard. Here, if the keyboard is still floating, you can try the method mentioned in the link in the above comment to lose the floating keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Jayesh, but still no luck unfortunately...